# Fetch HTML language and region of website

Tags: php

Short explanation :

This is piece of a code that I wrote and it's a part of a bigger script that I'm using to index my internal pages. What I'm trying to do is to fetch language and region of a website if there is specified. So far I have the following code which works but not in all cases.

Problem :

Sometimes where random page has those tags in place it's seems that for some reason they are not fetched.

Code :

```
//------- get contents of url file -------//

        $html = file_get_contents($link);

        // loading DOM document //
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        @$doc->loadHTML($html);

        // loading language & country tags
        $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('html');
        foreach ($tags as $tag) 
        {
            // getting lang and country property
            $lang_country = $tag->getAttribute('lang');

            $lang = array_shift(explode('-', $lang_country));

            if (strpos($lang_country, '-') !== false){

                $country = substr($lang_country, strpos($lang_country, '-') + 1);
                $country = strtoupper($country);

            }   
        };
```

Question :

Is there a better way of coding above or else 
is there any better way of getting those two values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe it or not but after some testing I added the following:

```
// strip whitespaces from url

        $link = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$link);
        $link = preg_replace(array('/\s{2,}/', '/[\t\n]/'), ' ', $link);
        $link = preg_replace("/[[:blank:]]+/"," ",$link);
        $link = preg_replace('~\x{00a0}~','',$link);
```

and then 99% of cases not found where I knew the region tag was there was finally found. So I think I solved myself my own problem. Well Thank You me.